# Setting session length with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My sessions with devise timeout after 1-3 hours of non-use (not sure exactly how long). How can I adjust this?

I've looked over the docs and can't seem to find a setting for this.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Look in config/initializers/devise.rb. There are a lot of configuration settings including `config.timeout_in`. The default in my version is 30 minutes. You can also set it on the model itself:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :timeoutable, :timeout_in => 15.minutes
```

You can now also [set the timeout dynamically](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-timeout_in-value-dynamically).

Comment: Is it safe to set it to 2 weeks for example?

Answer (score 15):

With Rails4, the better thing to follow is:

In models/user.rb: Add **:timeoutable** to already existing list of devise modules.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :timeoutable
end
```

In config/initializers/devise.rb: Set the timeout parameter.

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.timeout_in = 3.hours
end
```

Answer (score 13):

Global:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise (...), :timeoutable
end

Devise.setup do |config|
  config.timeout_in = 3.hours
end
```

Also it's possible to set timeout_in option dynamically

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise (...), :timeoutable

  def timeout_in
    if self.admin? 
      1.year
    else
      2.days
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes! Except perhaps you'd want to reverse the times there. Better to make users with more privileges authenticate more frequently...