# Ruby Rails Session timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, timeout

I'm using Ruby1.8.7 & rails 3.1.0. I want to increase session timeout. I  already gone through the existingg threads  but didn't helped me.

Please guide.

Comment: What kind of session? How are you using it?

Comment: You should also upgrade to 1.9.2, there are many benefits you are missing out on.

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely using devise.  In this case, [follow these suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867298/setting-session-length-with-devise).  Ensure you add `:timeoutable` as a module in the devise model as well.