# Rails/Devise - Determining when user session will expire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden

When using the `timeoutable` module for Devise, how can one determine how long it will be before the current user's session expires?  The goal is to include this value in all responses so client side script can make use of it.  I gather that Devise internally uses Warden for authentication, but I haven't found anything that explains how to pull the session expiration time out of the depths of Warden.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is how you do it:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :authenticatable, :timeoutable, :validatable, :timeout_in => 20.minutes
end
```

Comment: I knew that, but it took your post to make me realize it was actually the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: What if I want 1 user to have different timeout and another user to different?

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you can put it in the model as Benjamin Tan says, or you can put in **config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
# ==> Configuration for :timeoutable
# The time you want to timeout the user session without activity. After this
# time the user will be asked for credentials again. Default is 30 minutes.
# config.timeout_in = 30.minutes
```

See this StackOverflow question:  [Setting session length with Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867298/setting-session-length-with-devise).

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 4:

**config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
  if Rails.env.production?
    config.timeout_in = 30.minutes
  else
    config.timeout_in = 7.days
  end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :timeoutable
end
```