# What is the default timeout duration for a session/session variable in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been searching for this for a while, but haven't found a clear answer yet, only information to manually set expiry times. Also is there anything that would cause a session to be reset (apart from clearing cookies in a browser)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the Devise gem for session authentication, the default timeout length is 30 minutes. Couldn't find it in the Devise documentation, but this other SO thread below references it. As the thread solution to that thread mentions, you can override time in your User model, or also by editing the devise.rb config initializer file.

[Rails/Devise - Determining when user session will expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681825/rails-devise-determining-when-user-session-will-expire#answer-19284428)

Comment: Is there some evidence for this other than the commented-out default suggestion of `30.minutes`? Just because the commented-out value is 30 minutes doesn't necessarily mean that's the actual default.