# Testing Devise session timeout with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, session-timeout, warden

I'd like to customize the time period after which my Rails app will automatically end a user's session.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867298/setting-session-length-with-devise) to give me exactly what I need, but I'd like to approach this through TDD. I've got a relatively solid test suite for the application, I'm just a little lost when it comes to testing if a user's session has expired, other than having a test sit there and wait for the session to expire after `x.minutes` have elapsed. Surely there's a better way.

I checked the Devise and Warden documentation for test helpers dealing with this and came up dry. Anyone have any tips?

Comment: You don't need to test Devise functions such as timeout, because it is already tested in Devise.

Comment: You might try something like [timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop).  That should let you initiate your session in an integration test, and then fast-forward 30 minutes and check that it's expired.

Comment: The [Devise timeoutable tests](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/test/integration/timeoutable_test.rb) might have a clue. It looks like they call `get expire_user_path(user)` to simulate a timeout, but that gives an "undefined method" error in my RSpec tests.

Answer (score 3):

How about stubbing `user.timedout?` to return true? Or, you could pass a custom time in your test that exceeds your custom timeout value, like `user.timed_out?(31.minutes.ago)`.

Answer (score 1):

By default device set timeout to 30 minutes.
you can used `user.timedout?([specify time in past])`

ex:

`user.timedout?(30.minutes.ago)` will return false

`user.timedout?(10.minutes.ago)` will return true

you can check `user.timedout?()` value inside rspec.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of playing with exact time elapsed:

Since Devise is built on Warden, you can simulate that Devise::SessionsController has timed out the User by way of Warden::Test::Helpers that give access to the Rack proxy.

```
# settings_page_spec.rb

include Warden::Test::Helpers

it 'does not allow updating password after timed out' do
  expect(current_path).to eq(user_settings_path(user))
  clink_link 'Manage Password'
    expect(page).to have_button('Update Password')
    Warden.on_next_request do |proxy|
      proxy.set_user(nil)
      click_button 'Update Password'
      expect(current_path).to eq(login_path)
    end
end
```

Full blog post here: http://www.morphogenic.net/2016/10/devise-test-timeout-user-in-featureintegration-specs-using-warden/