# Can't login immediately following user session timeout (Devise Gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

The issue I'm having is that if my user session gets timed out (using the devise gem), I'll try to go to another screen and it will take me back to the login page which is correct. However, the url does not change from the page I was trying to go to before the timeout.

So for example, the session will end but I'll still be taken here if that's where I was heading before the timeout: `http://localhost:3000/users/edit`

The problem with this is that it disallows me from logging in until I refresh the page--which changes the url to this instead: `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in`.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**:

The log represents two different browser tabs of the same session. The first two paragraphs show the user logging out and the last two paragraphs show what it looks like when the user (who still looks like they are logged in on the second tab) tries to go to a different page. The main difference is that the log doesn't show the "Started GET "/projects/messageChannel"" for the second tab. But it does appear when I hit a refresh.
Server log below:

```
Started GET "/" for XXXXXXX at 2014-06-18 10:09:53 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.slim (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 10.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/projects/messageChannel" for XXXXXXX at 2014-06-18 10:09:53 -0400
Processing by ProjectsController#messageChannel as JSON
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms


Started GET "/dashboard/2" for XXXXXXX at 2014-06-18 10:09:59 -0400
Processing by UsersController#dashBoard as HTML
  Parameters: {"foo"=>"dashBoard", "id"=>"2"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for XXXXXXX at 2014-06-18 10:09:59 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.slim (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 10.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Yes, just edited it into my question.

Comment: If you are using timeoutable, try to set timeout length as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867298/setting-session-length-with-devise

Comment: It's not the timeout length which is the problem, it's what happens after the session has timed out. If you look at the log above, they represent two different browser tabs of the same session. The first two paragraphs show the user logging out and the last two paragraphs show what it looks like when the user (who still looks like they are logged in on the second tab) tries to go to a different page. The main difference is that the log doesn't show the "Started GET "/projects/messageChannel"" for the second tab. But it does appear when I hit a refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was right in front of me. I removed Turbolinks from the app and that fixed the issue. Basically, because of Turbolinks it was just rendering the page without actually reloading anything (javascript files etc).