# Ruby on Rails: When session expired, do something

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

Basic problem is; I want to make some changes on database when users session expired.

For example, user is an employee and while he is working on application, session is active and his working status is "active" on the database. If he loaf around, session will get expired and when session expired Rails should change his working status to "idle" on database automatically.

I am storing session data on Redis. I checked it manually and I discovered Redis is cleaning expired sessions data automatically/itself. If Redis can do this, I must also do.

I can check sessions manually with a Rake task and cron job but it's not good solution I think.

No log quote or code snippet. I just need methods and ideas, thanks.

Update: I can't add additional gem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867298/setting-session-length-with-devise might help you

Comment: @RajarshiDas Many thanks for your advice but I don't want to add any gem for this simple problem. I am looking for basic, low level solution.

Comment: first get the login time/session_id create time while authenticate if Time.now - login time  or  session_id create time > 60 minutes or your deadline time then do the data base operation and logout or `reset_session` may be help you

Comment: @RajarshiDas yeah, it's almost perfect solution but i need a planned worker(like cron) for this, is not it?