# Devise reset sessions each day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to automatically expired sessions that was not started today, for example, if the sign in was yesterday at 11PM, the first action of the next day should be ask for login again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting session length with Devise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867298/setting-session-length-with-devise)

Answer (score 0):

Add `config.timeout_in = 1.day.beginning_of_day` to your config/initializers/devise.rb

This will log all users out at midnight.