# How should "remember me" work in Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using [Rememberable](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Strategies/Rememberable) on Devise and I have some questions:

- how should it work?
- should it save your password for a specific time?
- for which reason 'remember_for' option exists?

I tried to test checking and not checking 'remember me' option and the behavior is the same: even when I close the browser, if a go back to my application I keep logged.

Answer (score 0):

Devise's Rememberable means it stores the user information in a cookie , so when they come back to your site they wont have to log back in for the specified amount of time

Comment: But it happens even if I don't check 'remember me' option.

Comment: This might give you a little better idea on how long the sessions last and how to change the default settings. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867298/setting-session-length-with-devise)